# Get the current selected row from IList

Tags: wpf

My XAML file:

```
<Grid>
        <DataGrid x:Name="LibraryView" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Elements[track]}"  SelectionChanged="LoadAlbumDetails" SelectionMode="Single">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Artist" Binding="{Binding Path=Element[artist_name].Value}"  />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Album" Binding="{Binding Path=Element[album_name].Value}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Length" Binding="{Binding Path=Element[duration].Value}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Price" Binding="{Binding Path=Element[price].Value}"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
```

My XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<albums>
    <track>
        <id>211</id>
        <name>If you say something..</name>
        <duration>156</duration>
        <artist_id>13</artist_id>
        <artist_name>Richard Keating</artist_name>
        <album_id>29</album_id>
        <album_name>Don't say anything..</album_name>
        <price>$10</price>
   </track>

   <track>
        <id>212</id>
        <name>My heart is a stereo</name>
        <duration>150</duration>
        <artist_id>14</artist_id>
        <artist_name>Maroon 5</artist_name>
        <album_id>30</album_id>
        <album_name>Maroon 5 stereo</album_name>
        <price>$15</price>
   </track>
</albums>
```

In my xaml.cs file

```
  protected void LoadAlbumDetails(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
  {
    IList rows = LibraryView.SelectedItems;

  }
```

How do i get the name(album name) from the selected rows?

ie.

```
?rows[0].ToString()
"<track>\r\n  <id>212</id>\r\n  <name>My heart is a stereo</name>\r\n  <duration>150</duration>\r\n  <artist_id>14</artist_id>\r\n  <artist_name>Maroon 5</artist_name>\r\n  <album_id>30</album_id>\r\n  <album_name>Maroon 5 stereo</album_name>\r\n  <price>$15</price>\r\n</track>"
```

I want to fetch out the album name alone separately? Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cast the item to its type, i assume that would be `XElement` or something similar here. e.g.

```
XElement row = (XElement)rows[0];
// <do something with row, access values etc.>
row.Element("name").Value;
```

Comment: ?row.Value
"212My heart is a stereo15014Maroon 530Maroon 5 stereo$15"

I want to extract  My heart is a stereo via <name>My heart is a stereo</name> tag. This is very close.

Comment: Ok this one did it.

?row.Element("name").Value